# Python Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time'

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, activestate, constant-time

I'm trying to run a script that I've been able to run in the past.  It stops with error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time'
```

I recently removed python 3.6 and installed python ActiveState:

```
ActivePython 3.6.0.3600 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan 23 2017, 20:01:14) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Things I've tried thus far:

Re-installing cryptography

Re-installing cryptography but I get an error:

```
Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\includ
e\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tcbuild\temp.win-amd64
-3.6\Release\_openssl.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_openssl.obj
  error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cryptography
  Running setup.py clean for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  I'm fairly new to python but I'm at a loss

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the version that was released today actually broke something; using `cryptography==2.5` might get you past that error until they fix 2.6.